# Event.preventDefault() not functioning when JQuery Post Command is issued

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I am trying to send a form value as through POST to a server PHP script with JQuery. Unfortunately, when the POST command is introduced, the event.preventDefault() command fails to execute and the page is reloaded.

Have already tried the stopPropagation() command.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#login").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //some functions
    alert(Alpha);
    $.post("URL", "a=".concat(String(Alpha)))
      .done(function(data) {
        alert(data);
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Before the $.post is introduced, the preventDefault command works perfectly. But then it suddenly fails to work. Note that the code above is written in the head.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: there is smth wrong with your `"a=".concat(String(Alpha))`. is your `Alpha` defined somewhere above? can you post the output of `console.log("a=".concat(String(Alpha)))`?

Comment: Also, are you getting any console errors when you run this?  That could cause the preventDefault() from working as expected.

Comment: You have a syntax error. You are missing a `)` on the `$.post` line. Next time, check your browser console for errors

Comment: @Phil That seems to have come up when I transferred the code to stack overflow. It's not there in my code.

Comment: I managed to find one work around. It turns out my Alpha is a very large value (~500kB) If I post a smaller Alpha, things seem to work. But is there a way to circumvent this?